# Calculating the Fourier Integral Representation of $f(x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Considering the function $f(x) = e^{-x}, x>0$ and $f(-x) = f(x)$. I am trying to find the Fourier integral representation of $f(x)$. Below are my workings but I am not sure if I proceeded correctly or how to use $f(-x)=x$. Also since the function is for $x>0$ should I use a low bound of $0$ and upper bound of $\infty$ for the integrals.

**My attempt:**

Using the formula for the Fourier integral representation,

$$f(x) = \int_0^\infty \left( A(\alpha)\cos\alpha x +B(\alpha) \sin\alpha x\right) d\alpha$$

Calculating $A(\alpha),$

$$A(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)\cos\alpha u du = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-u}\cos \alpha u du$$

**Notice here how I used $0$ and $\infty$ as my bounds, is this correct?**

Below is the calculation of this integral, I will save myself sometime and just post the answer I got.

$$A(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\alpha ^2 +1}$$

Calculting $B(\alpha),$

$$B(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)\sin\alpha u du = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-u}\sin \alpha u du$$

**Notice again here how I used $0$ and $\infty$ as my bounds, is this correct?**

Below is the calculation of this integral, I will save myself sometime and just post the answer I got.

$$B(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2 +1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-j\omega x}dx$$

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)e^{j\omega x}d\omega$$

Expand the first formula yielding

$F(\omega)=A(\omega)+jB(\omega)$

where, $A(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)cos(\omega x)dx$, 
$B(\omega)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)sin(\omega x)dx$

Since $f(x)$ is an even function, $B(\omega)=0$. All you have to do is caculate $A(\omega)$

$$A(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)cos(\omega x)dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)cos(\omega x)dx=\frac{2}{1+\omega ^2}$$

Hence,
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{1+\omega ^2}e^{j\omega x}\,d\omega}$$

Comment: have I calculated $A(w)$ correctly? and what about the coefficient of $\frac{1}{\pi}$ in the formulas?

Comment: Expand the formular is a rigorous. way to calculate the integral. However an convenient way is simplely treat $j$ as an real constant and the result usually is correct.

Comment: @fr14 Very close but not correct.

Comment: where have I gone wrong? should the bounds not be 0 to infinity?

Comment: and this is how to calculate the fourier integral representation correct?

Comment: @fr14 pleast note that $f(x)$ is defined on R,  not half of it.

Comment: so I need to calculate it from -infinity to infinity?

Comment: @fr14 yes. and mind the definition of fourier transform. Your formula maybe is not correct you can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform?wprov=sfla1
. There is numerous different definition of fourier transform but they gave the same fourier integral representation formula.   maybe the \frac{1}{\pi} should be corrected as \frac{1}{2\pi}

Comment: okay so the integral would be $$A(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int f(u)\cos\alpha u du = \frac{1}{\pi} \int e^{-u}\cos \alpha u du = \frac{1}{\pi } \frac{e^{-x}(\alpha sin(\alpha x)- (cos(\alpha x ))}{\alpha ^2 + 1}$$ but how would I calculate it for -infinity to infinity

Comment: Again the coefficient is1/2pi not 1/pi and the function is an even function it is symmetric about the y axis. Split the integral into two part: the negetive part and the positive part. The two parts havethe same value.

Comment: sorry I forgot to edit that into my post there. Could you show me how to integrate that from -infinity to infinity? then I will be done

Comment: @fr14 see the answe.

Comment: okay so the answer is only integrating from 0 to infinity, and that's correct? thankyou btw

Comment: how exactly does the $\pi$ cancel out?

Comment: @fr14 it is not cancelled. See the second formula of my answer it is there.

Comment: the answer that I see is,

$$A(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)cos(\omega x)dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)cos(\omega x)dx=\frac{2}{1+\omega ^2}$$

Comment: @fr14 I have updata my answer.

Comment: thanks for your update! I will accept the answer now. should the exponent in your solution be negative or positive?.... if you were to do the same problem with the function $g(x) = e^{-x}$, x>0 and $g(-x) = -g(x)$ since $g(x)$ is a odd function would I just need to calculate B?

Comment: @fr14 yes, in this case A(w) is is zero.

Comment: is your final answer suppose to have a negative or positive exponent?

Comment: @fr14 sorry, imade a mistake, it should be positive.

Comment: okay final question, thanks again. Do I need to evaluate that integral? or is that the answer?

Comment: @fr14 it is the answer. If you try to evaluate, you will find the answer is exactly $f(x)$. But it is difficult to do it in real field. An simple way to do this integral is do it in complex field utilizing residue theorem. you can try it.

Comment: thanks for everything!